# AI: Offset Path to reduce the thickness of a vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I downloaded this icon from flaticon and want to reduce the thickness of the path:

http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/bird-in-broken-egg_44434#term=broken%20egg&page=1&position=2

[image]

I followed the guide here: http://projectwoman.com/2011/05/make-a-path-bigger-or-smaller-in-illustrator.html and used the offset path function but it just doesn't seem to do anything if I make the offset a negative number:

[image]

If I make it a positive number, I can see the paths will increase in thickness. Why will it not reduce in thickness if I make it negative?

Comment: For one, enable preview.  Two, try a smaller value.  -10 in seems like quite a bit, but then again, maybe your graphic is ridiculously large.

Comment: Yes i did enable the preview, I just didn't show that in my screenshot but it is enabled. I have also tried it with -3 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I downloaded that vector and I can say, without any shadow of doubt, that the values you are using are MUCH too large.  I just tried it with a value of -1px and that was still too large.  To make it easier, you should make the entire image larger first, then try to offset the path.  I can demonstrate in a minute...

Comment: OK thanks - I'm quite a new AI user so I can use all the help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having an issue, because the source file is *tiny*.

To illustrate this, I increased the object's size by 500% (Object > Transform > Scale):

[image: scale]

At 500% scale, you can finally begin to notice the offset path (-1 px here):

[image: offset]

I would increase your object's size, to begin with.  Alternatively, you can try to mess around with small decimals to offset your path, but that seems much more difficult, to me.

Comment: Thanks, it is now working properly. I increased the size and then used the offset path method.